# You must log in before using this part of Bugzilla

Tags: c#, rest, get, bugzilla, web-api-testing

I have an issue with this get request of bugzilla to get the page of bug_list of two bugs "http://10.0.6.199:8080/bugzilla/rest.cgi/bug?id=2313,3478?api_key=my_api_key"
The issue appeared when I write more than one bug id to get the page of bug_list, I get this response

> {
>   "code" : 410,
>   "documentation" : "http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/tip/en/html/api/", 
>     "error" : true,
>   "message" : "You must log in before using this part of Bugzilla." 
>   }

but I have no issus when I write one id by this get request
http://10.0.6.199:8080/bugzilla/rest.cgi/bug/2313?api_key=my_api_key
Can any one tell me the problem with this get request link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem, I should write '&' before `api_key` instead of '?'

> http://10.0.6.199:8080/bugzilla/rest.cgi/bug?id=2313,3478&api_key=my_api_key

instead of

> http://10.0.6.199:8080/bugzilla/rest.cgi/bug?id=2313,3478?api_key=my_api_key"